# Is number of individuals a dimensioned quantity?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dimensional-analysis, unit-of-measure

I am learning about non-dimensionalization, and how to apply it to ODEs. My question comes from the following predator-prey system:

\begin{align*}
    \frac{dx}{dt} &= r_1 x \Big(1-\frac{x}{K_1}\Big) - b_1 xy, \\[5pt]
    \frac{dy}{dt} &= r_2 y \Big(1-\frac{y}{K_2}\Big) - b_2 xy,
\end{align*}

(Here, $r_1,r_2$ are per-capita growth rates, $K_1,K_2$ are carrying capacities, and $b_1$ and $b_2$ measure inter-species competition.) Let's say that $x(t) = $ number of foxes and $y(t) = $ number of rabbits at time $t$. My main question is: Are $x$ and $y$ dimensioned quantities? If so, would their dimensions be "number of foxes" and "number of rabbits", respectively?

In the examples I have come across in my textbook, the units of the variables have all been expressed in terms of the fundamental dimensions, time (T), length (L), and mass (M) (and sometimes temperature $\Theta$.) If rabbits and foxes could be considered the dimensions of $x$ and $y$, respectively, could we say that rabbits and foxes are also fundamental dimensions, since they cannot be expressed in terms of T,L,M?

In general, if we have a model which involves a number of "individuals"--be it atoms, cells, people, cars--are these always considered dimensioned quantities? Is there a general rule of thumb that we can use to say if a given quantity is dimensioned/dimensionless?

Comment: You could express $x,y$ as fractions of the carrying capacities. This might reduce the number of parameters in the equation. This reduction of parameters is the main goal of the non-dimensionalization, as that frequently leads to a normalized system that is easier to discuss.

Answer (score 0):

They're dimensionless. You can work out the parameters' dimensions now.

Comment: Ok, but could you provide some more explanation? What makes $x$ and $y$ dimensionless? Is it because they do not have units involving $T,L,M$?

Comment: @Leonidas I'd argue the causation goes the other way. Object counts are dimensionless because e.g. number of teams = (number of people)/(number of people per team) is a ratio of two people counts.